# Directory doesn't exist, but it does, but it doesn't

Tags: networking, command-line, network-shares, ubuntu-14.04

Before I start, my `/etc/fstab` file has the line:

```
//10.10.10.1/Atkins ~/Desktop/Atkins cifs rw
```

Ubuntu is giving me strange issues. I'm trying to mount a directory, so I type:

```
sudo mount //10.10.10.1/Atkins
```

which returns:

> Couldn't chdir to ~/Desktop/Atkins: No such file or directory

(I do know this folder exists btw.) So to be sure, i try to create it again with:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/Atkins
```

Which returns:

> mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/classroom/Desktop/Atkins': File exists

So basically, the computer is simultaneously convinced the folder exists, but can't map a network share to it, because it doesn't... Deleting and re-creating the folder doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` is resolvable in your shell but `mount` has no idea what it means to the shell and to you. Use full path.

---

The command like

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o rw //10.10.10.1/Atkins ~/Desktop/Atkins
```

should work because the shell expands `~` and passes full path to `mount`. Yet if `mount` reads its arguments from `/etc/fstab` then it treats `~` literally as a part of the target path; hence *no such file or directory*.

Comment: awesome. This did fix that error. Maybe this is a quick answer, but maybe i'll have to open another thread. Now it asks for the password for root@//10.10.10.1/Atkins. The share does not have a password, and just hitting enter doesn't work. What to do?

Comment: According to  [this man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) you need `guest` option. Try `rw,guest` instead of just `rw` in your `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: tried that. now I just get a mount Error(13): Permission denied

Comment: We are going off topic. Maybe you can access the share with `user=<right_name_here>` option. It depends on server (and share) configuration you should know.

Comment: ah well, that doesn't work. Looks like it will be lengthy. I will open a new thread if I can't figure it out. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @Blaine From [this site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1589669): *So, even if you give a Windows share read/write access, you still need to add "Everyone" to the permissions to connect from your Linux box.* May help.

Comment: Yeah, this is a share directly from the router USB port, so it's a bit confusing. I think the router was set up with Windows in mind

Comment: eh, for what I had in mind i'm just going to mount it by using >nautilus smb://10.10.10.1/Atkins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40375/discussion-between-kamil-maciorowski-and-blaine).